# How to use require in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 3 files:

Child1:

```
var Parent = require('./Parent');
Parent['type'] = 'Child1';
module.exports = Parent;
```

Child2:

```
var Parent = require('./Parent');
Parent['type'] = 'Child2';
module.exports = Parent;
```

Parent:

```
module.exports = { 'parent' : 1 }
```

test.js:

```
var test1 = require('./Child1')
var test2 = require('./Child2')
```

Result:

```
{ parent: 1, type: 'Child2' }
----
{ parent: 1, type: 'Child2' }
```

Why ?

Comment: As dystroy noted, module cached by path as key.  Note that if you need two instances of object/state coming from that same module, then you need a JS object pattern with new.

Comment: OP, can you explain why you didn't accept the answer ? What is missing ?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) :

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
>   (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
>   exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.

This is especially convenient not only for performances but for module initialization. If you want different objects, change your module to a factory.